# React Firebase Logout

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

In my app.js I have:

```
<IconButton size="small" onClick={() => firebase.auth().signOut()}>
  <ExitToAppIcon />
</IconButton>
```

This signs the user out (if I refresh the page) but hangs otherwise.

I get the console error of:

> Uncaught Error in snapshot listener: FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.

It looks to be related back to the snapshot, as an example:

```
const useItems = () => {
  const user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
  const user1 = user.uid;
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("gear")
      .where("User", "==", user1)
      .orderBy("Name", "asc")
      .onSnapshot(snapshot => {
        const listItems = snapshot.docs.map(doc => ({
          id: doc.id,
          Name: doc.data().Name
        }));
        setItems(listItems);
      });
  }, []);
  return items;
};
```

If I have a component that does not use the onsnapshot it works fine. How can I force the user to logout successfully?

Comment: Were you able to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your security rules require that the user is signed in before they can read the database, which is a good thing.

But that means you need to disconnect the listener from the database, before you sign the user out.

```
<IconButton size="small" onClick={() => { unsubscribe(); firebase.auth().signOut()} }>
```

Note that:

- Even if you don't unsubscribe, the user is still signed out after you called: `firebase.auth().signOut()`. In fact, the error message comes from the fact that the user was signed out, so the client no longer has permission to read the data.
- The error message also removes the listener. So the end result between your original code, and my code with the `unsubscribe()` call is the same, it's just that calling `unsubscribe()` doesn't show an error message.

Comment: Thanks @Frank van Puffelen - I saw this in other posts, but when using the unsubscribe() I get 'unsubscribe' is not defined  no-undef - my snapshot is in other component - the signOut is part of app.js - so I need to somehow sort a const out in app.js?